# linear algebra, dimension of vector of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $v$, $w$ are linearly independent vectors of $R^3$ then the subspace of $R^3$ generated by the vecors $v$,$w$ and $v-w$ is of dimension

$A)\quad 1$

$B)\quad2$

$C)\quad3$

$D)\quad-1$

I am thinking in this question as $v$, $w$ are linearly independent so $v-w$ is linearly dependent so dimension of linearly dependent vectors is always less then $\dim(R^3)$ so is the answer $2$ ? am I correct or not? Please help me out to solve this.

Comment: Does answer (d) really say $-1$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Probably to select people who definety should not study.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut They are definetyly not linear. :-) But I understand: according to some agreements a polynomial equal to zero has degree $-\infty$.

Comment: Let try to improve a little bit your question also fixing some typos.

Comment: v and w are linearly independent so they span a plane. v-w is the linear combination of v and w, so it is in the plane.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Note that $v-w$ is a linear combination of $v$ and $w$ that is

- $v-w=1\cdot v-1\cdot w$

or also that in the basis $\{v,w,z\}$, with $z$ a third linearly independent vector, we have

- $v=(1,0,0)$
- $w=(0,1,0)$
- $v-w=(1,-1,0)$

Comment: Is that answer so bad?

Comment: @amd sorry I need an you advice here, is my answer uncorrect? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $w$ and $v$ are linearly independent, so dimension is at least 2. Why the dimension of a space generated by $v$, $w$, $v-w$ must be less than 3?

Your selection is correct, but your answer doesn't explain, why the dimension is not equal to 1.